# Cannot import name 'function' from 'module.py' - same directory, another function from the same module imports

Tags: python, python-3.x, importerror

I have a Jupyter Notebook - we'll call it `main`, and I'm running it piecemeal in Jupyter Lab 3.0.14 using a Python 3 environment.

Within this notebook, I'm trying to import custom functions from a module, we'll call this one `module.py`, which is in the same directory as `main`.

It looks something like this:

//`main`

```python
import sys
import os
from module import foo, bar
```

//`module.py`

```python
def foo():
    return

def bar():
    return
```

When I run the import statements in `main`, it throws an error

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'bar' from 'module' (/module.py)
```

If I run

```python
from module import foo
```

or

```python
from module import *
```

It's fine (although calling the functions will throw an error that the function `is not defined`). In fact, it will import `foo` even if there's no function named `foo` in `module.py`. It won't import any of my own functions by name. I feel like I must be missing something fundamental, here...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: I would assume there's some syntax/dependency issue with function b that prevents it from being imported. Can you actually replace the module contents with your example contents (two blank functions) and give it a try? If it works, try to leave only one function in the module, and give it a try again

Comment: I changed the contents of `module.py` to two blank functions, `foo` and `bar` like in my example, which both import fine. Here's the weird thing: When I change the name of the problem function (with its original content) to `foo`, it imports totally fine, in fact, it seems to import `foo` even if there's no function by that name in `module.py`. If I replace the names of my totally blank example functions, they refuse to import, as well.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this is my first time using Jupyter Lab, and this problem came from a fundamental misunderstanding of how Jupyter (and maybe other IDEs?) manages packages.

In short, as I understand it, re-running the code which imported functions from `module.py` did not actually re-import the contents. The only things it imported were what I asked for the first time, and any subsequent calls to import functions only referenced that first static image I pulled.

Therefore, if `module.py` had one function, `foo`, and I ran:

```python
from module import foo
```

...then made some changes, such as editing the contents of `foo` and adding `bar`, running:

```python
from module import foo, bar
```

...didn't actually do anything but reference that first copy of `module.py` I pulled. Because `bar` didn't exist the first time I ran the import function, it "couldn't see it", no matter how many times I re-ran the import function. I had to restart the kernel to fix it, basically.

I noticed this because when I changed the name of the script, it would import the functions that weren't previously working, but then edits to the functions, even once imported, weren't recognized.

[This link](https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/204469240-Jupyter-IPython-After-editing-a-module-changes-are-not-effective-without-kernel-restart) provided the clue I needed to figure this out.

Hopefully this helps somebody!

Answer (score 1):

Restart the kernel in the Jupiter notebook. I solved a similar import name issue by restarting the kernel.